# Regarding validation rule and test code coverage in salesforce

Tags: validation

For validation rules can we write test code coverage. if that so all the validation rule test code coverage can be maintained in one class?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about

- ***Setup > Customize > Object > Validation Rules*** (for standard objects) or
- ***Setup > Create > Objects > custom_Object__c > Validation Rules***(custom objects)

No. Salesforce does not require or there's nothing like code coverage for validation rules.

But when you write unit tests, you may consider validation rules you have defined because your DMLs inside your test class can be failed if you are violating any validation rules defined.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate test classes for your validation rules.

Validation rules are part of business logic to ensure data quality, however you can deploy them to production without any test classes.

Salesforce requires test classes to validate your business logic in an automated manner. If you have a validation rule and a trigger on an object, you can assert the validation failure in your test class to verify the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

While separate test methods for Validation Rules are not required by SFDC, you might want to use Apex testmethods for that purpose.  Here are some reasons:

1. You have VRs that are complex with many conditional expressions
2. You have VRs that are subject to change by sysads who might not be "the most diligent testers" or who make changes directly in PROD (not ideal, but it happens)
3. You just have a complex system and want to make sure all the parts keep working on every deployment

Now you could use something like Selenium to test Validation Rules that would appear on the UI but if you have an existing robust APEX testmethod regression test infrastructure that does asserts rather than just code coverage, extending your testmethods to cover the conditional paths through your VRs may make sense.

If you do go that route, something I've found useful is to give every VR error message a code or number in the actual error text so you can assert against that value without binding your testmethod assert to the actual language of the error message (something that can change over time with better grammar or tips to the end user)

Comment: When deploying data to production because of validation rule overall code coverage is becoming low. Everytime cannot disable validation rules as there are many. so wanted to write testclass for this

Comment: Then this sounds like you have situation#2 above - your PROD environment is not mirrored with respect to metadata (including VRs) in your sandbox.  So, if you can't get that under control, the testmethods will at least help identify where the environment has changed so you can then go "hunting for heads"